# Aperture: Import content of smart folder

Tags: aperture, smart-folders

Is there any way to import the content of *Smart Folder* into Aperture library?

Or may be choose any criteria during importing, like file kind, date etc.

BTW: Can I see a size of all *checked* files?

**Update**: I know I can choose from this set but may be any more options...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to import the content of Smart Folder into Aperture library?

The only way I found is to select all content of Smart Folder in Finder and drag it into Aperture project.